# Decode JSON from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase real-time Database, but some fields contain Russian text, so I need to decode them into something readable.

Below you can see how Russian text looks like in console.

[image]

Comment: The decoding is fine. Assign the text to a label or other UI element then you will see the Cyrillic letters.

Comment: @vadian I don't think that will work directly (???) The *\U043f* isn't a valid escape sequenced string. However, *"\u{043f}\u{043e}\u{0434}\u{0437}\u{0430}\u{0433}"* is so one solution is to break the string into it's individual chars and add the appropriate escape sequence to each and combine back together. Maybe there's another more automated solution?

Comment: @Jay It will work, believe me. The output is a typical output of a Foundation `NSDictionary`. Please prove in a Playground `let cyrill = "Привет мир", let dict = ["name" : cyrill]; print(dict as NSDictionary)`

Comment: @vadian I believe you. However, when I put this line into Xcode *let test = "\U043f\U043e\U0434\U0437\U0430\U0433"*, The compiler complains "Invalid Escape Sequence In Literal" and won't compile until the line is reformatted.

Comment: @Jay Yes because in a literal string the backslashes must be escaped, that's a different situation.

Comment: @vadian I was using the string the OP included in his question. Perhaps I misunderstand the use-case.

Comment: @Jay Once again, it's the console output of `print`ing an `NSDictionary`. It's **not** a simple string

Comment: @vadian I see! Very interesting. You should post that as an answer as it would probably help others!